# При нажатии на инлайн клавишу не выбивало новое сообщение от тг бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я бы хотел сделать чтобы в моем боте при нажатии на инлайн клавишу не выбивало новое сообщение от бота вот как на фото
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я бы хотел что бы сразу было все в оном разу без нових смс от бота вот как на этом фото
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]]

[[image: v]]

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
  if call.message:
        if call.data == "phone":
            bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]